# NSMutablearray move object from index to index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have a UItableview with reordable rows and the data is in an NSarray. So how do I move an object in the NSMutablearray when the appropriate tableview delegate is called?

Another way to ask this is how to reorder an NSMutableArray?

Comment: Listing 8-2 on [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html) in the Table View Programming Guide shows how to do this.

Comment: http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/11/15/moving-objects-within-an-nsmutablearray/

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
id object = [[[self.array objectAtIndex:index] retain] autorelease];
[self.array removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[self.array insertObject:object atIndex:newIndex];
```

That's all. Taking care of the retain count is important, since the array might be the only one referencing the object.

Comment: As you keep a pointer to the thing, there's not much reason to autorelease, is there? Rather than retaining before the remove, and releasing after the insert.

Comment: Yes, that's true. It's just that it's one line of code less, however I do understand your point that releasing it directly will be less expensive. I don't really mind for one object, however you'd better avoid this in a (tight) loop.

Comment: why not use 
- (void)exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx1 withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx2;

Comment: @SarenInden Because that method swaps the specified objects, not move a single one into a different position.

Answer (score 51):

ARC compliant category:

**NSMutableArray+Convenience.h**

```
@interface NSMutableArray (Convenience)

- (void)moveObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)fromIndex toIndex:(NSUInteger)toIndex;

@end
```

**NSMutableArray+Convenience.m**

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (Convenience)

- (void)moveObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)fromIndex toIndex:(NSUInteger)toIndex
{
    // Optional toIndex adjustment if you think toIndex refers to the position in the array before the move (as per Richard's comment)
    if (fromIndex < toIndex) {
        toIndex--; // Optional 
    }

    id object = [self objectAtIndex:fromIndex];
    [self removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndex];
    [self insertObject:object atIndex:toIndex];
}

@end
```

**Usage:**

```
[mutableArray moveObjectAtIndex:2 toIndex:5];
```

Comment: You'd better decrement `toIndex` if your `fromIndex` is less than your `toIndex`.

Comment: Richard's point is valid provided you are specifying a toIndex that refers to the position in the array before the move.  If that's your expectation then you probably should decrement the toIndex as suggested.  However if you are specifying a toIndex that refers to its final position in the array then you shouldn't decrement.

Comment: @OliverPearmain Sorry, I'm struggling to grasp that idea. Using your method (with the suggested decrement) an array `[A,B,C]` after a call to `moveObjectAtIndex:0 toIndex:1` would result in `[A,B,C]`. Is that logical?

Comment: `remove` effectively decrements the indexes of all objects after `fromIndex`.

Answer (score 14):

With Swift's `Array` it's as easy as this:

#### Swift 3

```
extension Array {
    mutating func move(at oldIndex: Int, to newIndex: Int) {
        self.insert(self.remove(at: oldIndex), at: newIndex)
    }
}
```

#### Swift 2

```
extension Array {
    mutating func moveItem(fromIndex oldIndex: Index, toIndex newIndex: Index) {
        insert(removeAtIndex(oldIndex), atIndex: newIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an `NSArray`, you can't move or reorder anything as it is immutable.

You need an `NSMutableArray`.   With that, you can add and replace objects which, of course, also means you can reorder the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `NSArray` is immutable. You can copy that array into an [`NSMutableArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (or use that in the first place). The mutable version has methods to move and exchange its items.

Comment: sorry i meant mutable, but there is no move method for nsmutablearray.

Comment: Sure there is. Try [`-exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:). Also, the various sorting methods.

Comment: No that switches 2 objects, I want to move 1.

Comment: As other posters have pointed out, you need to remove and re-add.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if I understand correctly, you can do:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView moveRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)fromIndexPath toIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) toIndexPath

{
    [self.yourMutableArray moveRowAtIndex: fromIndexPath.row toIndex: toIndexPath.row]; 
    //category method on NSMutableArray to handle the move
}
```

Then what you can do is to add a category method to NSMutableArray using – insertObject:atIndex: method to handle the move.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to find the code for the category method to implement, should it be an insert and then remove?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Tomasz but with out of range error handling

```
enum ArrayError: ErrorType {
    case OutOfRange
}

extension Array {
    mutating func move(fromIndex fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) throws {
        if toIndex >= count || toIndex < 0 {
            throw ArrayError.OutOfRange
        }
        insert(removeAtIndex(fromIndex), atIndex: toIndex)
    }
}
```