# Shift all elements in an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have an NSMutableArray that will start with 0 objects in it, but as the program progresses objects will be added to it. How can I shift all elements down, when a new element is added?

For example:

1) NSMutableArray array = 0 elements

2) NSMutableArray array = 1 element { [0,a]}

3) NSMutableArray array = 2 elements {[0, b], [1,a]}

4) NSMutableArray array = 3 elements {[0,c],[1,b],[2,c]}

As can be seen through the above list as objects are added to the array,  all current elements move down. However, I do not want my array to exceed a certain size (lets say 10 elements). When a element is pushed to 11 I want it "pushed" out of the array. How can I go about doing this?

Similar questions: [NSMutablearray move object from index to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349669/nsmutablearray-move-object-from-index-to-index)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
[array insertObject:object atIndex:0];
if ([array count] > 10) {
    [array removeLastObject];
}
```

The first line will automatically push the other elements out of the way, and the next bit just makes sure the array's length never exceeds 10.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that an `NSMutableArray` is the appropriate structure.  You are describing a size-limited stack; you are pushing new elements onto the front, and then elements can fall off the back.

Is it really necessary to set the index-value of your object to its index in the stack/array?