# moving objects in NSMutableArray without changing array size

Tags: nsmutablearray

I have a 'MutableArray' that I want to edit by moving different objects in it up and down the index via the method shown here: [NSMutablearray move object from index to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349669/nsmutablearray-move-object-from-index-to-index).

My problem is that Xcode first takes care of the 'removeObjectAtIndex' method before the 'insertObject:atIndex:' so the array actually shrinks in size which makes certain transitions impossible. An example would be if my 'array' has 3 members and I change the third member's index from 2 to 2 so nothing should happen but actually the app crashes because after the removal the index bound is now [0,1].

Below is the code I am using to implement the move in array, I also get a Parse Issue: Expected identifier error from the compiler at the 'if' statement right behind the `queue.count`. Any help on both would be much appreciated.

```
-(void)makeRankChange:(NSMutableArray *)queue{
    for (int queueCount =0; queueCount<queue.count; queueCount++) {
        QueueMember *member = [queue objectAtIndex:queueCount];
        if (member.rank != queueCount+1) {
            if ([0<member.rank] && [member.rank < [queue.count(expected identifier here:Im not sure why)]]) {
                [queue insertObject:member atIndex:member.rank-1];
                [queue removeObjectAtIndex:queueCount];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing the value at the index:

```
[queue replaceObjectAtIndex:queueCount withObject:member];
```

The error is most likely from the '[' brackets in the if statement

Comment: That's not applicable here. If my array is [a,b,c,d,e] and i want to move e to second spot. using ur method, the result would be [a,e,c,d,e] whereas I want [a,e,b,c,d]

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood.  You could use exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:

Comment: but if i use that on e and b then it becomes [a,e,c,d,b] whereas i want [a,e,b,c,d] i only want to move ONE object in the array to a new location and keep the rest of the order.

Comment: Probably will have to do something with a parallel array to achieve this