# Obj c editing array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

i have an array like this:

```
array[0] = @"object0"
array[1] = @"object1"
array[2] = @"object2"
array[3] = @"object3"
```

And:
1.How to delete one object, for example array[1] and get this:

```
array[0] = @"object0"
array[1] = @"object1"
array[2] = @"object2"
```

2.How to move object to other index, for example 3->1

```
array[0] = @"object0"
array[1] = @"object3"
array[2] = @"object2"
array[3] = @"object1"
```

Comment: Read the documentation for NSMutableArray.

Comment: What is `array`? `NSArray`? `NSMutableArray`? A C-array of `NSString`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [@[@"obj0",
                           @"obj1",
                           @"obj2",
                           @"obj3",
                           @"obj4"] mutableCopy];

// Remove object at Index 1
[array removeObject:array[1]];
NSLog(@"%@", array);

// Move item to new index
id object = array[3];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:3];
[array insertObject:object atIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try NSMutableArray:

```
// creation array
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@"object0",@"object1",@"object2",@"object3"]];

// remove object        
[array removeObject:@"object0"];
```

To move at other index look here: [NSMutablearray move object from index to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349669/nsmutablearray-move-object-from-index-to-index)