# Reorder NSArray based on UITableView Edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have an app filled with over 500 songs for churches.  I am adding a new feature, which will allow them to create a "slide show" of manually chosen songs.  The way the layout is now is that they have a `UITableView` of all the songs, and tapping a song adds that PPT's file location to an `NSArray`, and adds a checkmark to the row.  Following this, they can click the Preview button, which will give them a tableview of just the songs they have chosen, in the order they chose it.

I would like to allow editing mode to delete songs, or reorder them, but am not sure how to have that also reorder the `NSArray`, so that item 0 will be the first song they have on the tableview, not just the first one they tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have an array of songs, called `songsArray` which is used to populate table view. Then when reordering happens, add this method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
    NSObject *songToMove = [self.songsArray objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.songsArray removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.songsArray insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
```

Dont forget to implement `canMoveForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return YES;
}
```

This lets user to reorder all rows in your table view, if you don't want to let user to reorder specific rows, add check for `indexPath.row` and return `NO` for that row.

Comment: Thanks, how would this look in Obj-C, as I haven't converted all over to Swift.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go and see how it fares.

Comment: Ok, I have the canMoveRowAtIndexPath implemented, with the BOOL set to YES, but when I run the app and get to this view, I have no options of moving anything.

Comment: call this then, when you  want to start reordering table view: `tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)`

Comment: Sorry, obj-c. `[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`

Comment: Be aware that this is dangerous when not using ARC. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4351068/171436

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I think that very little number of projects, especially new ones, don't use ARC.

Comment: @Joost I don't have this particular code using ARC, but I did have the retain and autorelease for the NSObject.

Comment: Excellent, then you're all set!